# How to ouput an integer with positive sign and zeros preceding it

Tags: c++

I want a number to be displayed with a positive sign and three 0's preceding it, but what I am getting so far is 000+1 when what I want is +0001

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    int main(void)
    {
        int number = 1;

        cout << showpos;
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(5) << number << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also set [`std::internal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) flag. This way you will get your expected `+0001` - [test at ideone](https://ideone.com/PwmnUK).

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [std::internal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) manipulator is for. For example,

```
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << std::internal << -5 << std::endl;
```

prints "-0005" instead of "000-5" as without std::internal.